# how to fix "Direct use of $_SERVER Superglobal detected' in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, global-variable

I am having problem with module approval. and magento connect validation report generates following message

> Direct use of $_SERVER Superglobal detected

how can i use alternate for

> $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

in Magento 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using an helper class extending the `/Magento/Framework/App/Helper/AbstractHelper` class you can use the following:

```
$this->_remoteAddress
```

It is set in the `AbstractHelper` class constructor:

```
public function __construct(Context $context)
{
    $this->_moduleManager = $context->getModuleManager();
    $this->_logger = $context->getLogger();
    $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
    $this->_urlBuilder = $context->getUrlBuilder();
    $this->_httpHeader = $context->getHttpHeader();
    $this->_eventManager = $context->getEventManager();
    $this->_remoteAddress = $context->getRemoteAddress();
    $this->_cacheConfig = $context->getCacheConfig();
    $this->urlEncoder = $context->getUrlEncoder();
    $this->urlDecoder = $context->getUrlDecoder();
    $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
}
```

It comes from the `/Magento/Framework/App/Helper/Context.php` class:

```
/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress
 */
public function getRemoteAddress()
{
    return $this->_remoteAddress;
}
```

And it is an instance of `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress` :

```
/**
 * Retrieve Client Remote Address
 *
 * @param bool $ipToLong converting IP to long format
 * @return string IPv4|long
 */
public function getRemoteAddress($ipToLong = false)
{
    if ($this->remoteAddress === null) {
        foreach ($this->alternativeHeaders as $var) {
            if ($this->request->getServer($var, false)) {
                $this->remoteAddress = $this->request->getServer($var);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$this->remoteAddress) {
            $this->remoteAddress = $this->request->getServer('REMOTE_ADDR');
        }
    }

    if (!$this->remoteAddress) {
        return false;
    }

    return $ipToLong ? ip2long($this->remoteAddress) : $this->remoteAddress;
}
```

Comment: How can i get this in logo.phtml file direct.